# How to determine the number of nodes in a Redshift cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-java-sdk

I need to programmatically determine the number of nodes in a Redshift cluster. I was hoping the AWS Java APIs would provide it in a cluster description, but I am not able to locate it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, via [DescribeCluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeClusters.html). Each cluster within the region passed to the client is listed as a [Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_Cluster.html) item, which has a `NumberOfNodes` attribute. For instance:

```
final AmazonRedshiftClient client = new AmazonRedshiftClient(credentials).withRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Regions.US_WEST_2);
final DescribeClustersResult describeResult = client.describeClusters();
describeResult.getClusters()
              .stream()
              .forEach(cluster -> System.out.println(String.format("Cluster: %s \nNumber of nodes: %d",
                                                                   cluster.getClusterIdentifier(),
                                                                   cluster.getNumberOfNodes())));
```

Gives me:

```
Cluster: cluster-22gsextori36
Number of nodes: 1
Cluster: cluster-22gsextori38 
Number of nodes: 1
Cluster: cluster-22gsextori40 
Number of nodes: 1
```

Comment: I am attempting to add the import statement for AmazonRedshiftClient. The api  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/redshift/AmazonRedshiftClient.html said I should import com.amazonaws.services.redshift.AmazonRedshiftClient; however, there appears to not be a redshift path after services. Is there a different import statement I must use for this?

Comment: The documentation is correct, `AmazonRedshiftClient` is in `com.amazonaws.services.redshift`. Are you sure that you have imported the [right dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.10.60) and version? This file may have been moved recently.

Comment: Thank you. I had only unknowingly imported a partial aws-sdk dependency. I have now moved to this new dependency.